# Model an indexed API response with GraphQL

Tags: graphql

I have an API response where the data is an object of objects, indexed by ID. The response looks like this:

```
{
  things: {
    'id-a': {id: 'id-a', name: 'Alice'},
    'id-b': {id: 'id-b', name: 'Bob'}
  }
}
```

GraphQL wants you to know the names of your fields at compile-time. Obviously, I'm not going to do that when I write the schema for `things`. Is there any way to model this response in GraphQL?

Note that the objects under the IDs always have the same structure, so they *could* be modeled with GraphQL.

Comment: I don't understand the question and what you are trying to accomplish. What do you mean when you say model the response in GraphQL? What do you mean with explicitely naming each field? Your example has the explicit field names `id` and `name`, where's the problem?

Comment: I mean when I write the schema for `things`, I won't know the names of the fields, since those fields will be the IDs of the things being returned.

The objects under the IDs (that have `id` and `name`) aren't the problem. The problem is the fields directly under `things`.